# Как изменить переменную без вызова watch-функции?

Tags: vue.js

Есть таблица с фильтром и постраничным выводом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Template:

```
<FilterPanel class="mb-3" v-model="filter"></FilterPanel>
<v-data-table
        :headers="tableHeaders"
        :items="clients"
        item-key="id"
        hide-actions
        class="elevation-1"
        :loading="isLoading"
        select-all
        v-model="checkedItem"
>
    <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>
            <v-checkbox v-model="props.selected" primary hide-details></v-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td>{{ props.item.contact_date }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.phone }}</td>
    </template>
</v-data-table>

<div class="pt-2">
    <v-pagination 
        v-model="pagerPage" 
        :length="pagerPages" 
        total-visible="9"></v-pagination>
</div>
```

Js:

```
import FilterPanel from './FilterPanel.vue'

export default {
    data: () => ({
        isLoading: true,
        pagerPage: 1,
        pagerOnPage: 20,
        pagerTotal: 0,

        checkedItem: [],

        filter: {
            'date': '',
            'dateTo': '',
            'chapter': 'all'
        },

        tableHeaders: [
            { text: 'Дата контакта', value: 'date', sortable: false},
            { text: 'Клиент', value: 'client', sortable: false},
            { text: 'Телефон', value: 'phone', sortable: false}
        ],

        clients: []
    }),
    computed: {
        'pagerPages': function() {
            return Math.ceil(this.pagerTotal / this.pagerOnPage)
        }
    },
    components: {
        FilterPanel
    },
    methods: {
        loadList () {

            this.isLoading = true;

            return axios
                .get('...', {
                    params: {
                        'filter': this.filter,
                        'page': this.pagerPage,
                        'onPage': this.pagerOnPage
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.isLoading = false;

                    this.clients = response.data.clients;
                    this.pagerTotal = response.data.pagination.total;
                });

        }
    },
    watch: {
        pagerPage: {
            handler () {
                this.loadList()
            },
            immediate: true
        },
        filter: {
            handler () {
                this.pagerPage = 1;
                this.loadList()
            },
            deep: true
        }
    }
}
```

Когда пользователь меняет фильтр (например нажимает кнопку "сегодня"), нужно переключиться на первую страницу (this.pagerPage = 1)
но тогда срабатывает watch-функция для pagerPage.
Получается два запроса на сервер при смене фильтра.

Или если нужно сбросить все фильтры:

```
this.filter = defaultFilter;
this.pagerPage = 1;
```

также 2 запроса.

Как это можно правильно решить?

*пример упрощенный. в реальности есть еще два компонента с фильтрами по типу FilterPanel*

Comment: Зачем переключать страницу? Не правильная логика пагинации у Вас... обычно, номер страницы определяется динамически, на основании каких-то данных... например, таких параметров как `offset`, `limit`, `total`

Comment: @Дмытрык
пользователь на 3й странице и применяет фильтр.. ведь не оставить его на 3й странице.
а если по фильтру есть только одна страница?..

общее количество записей возвращается сервером:
this.pagerTotal = response.data.pagination.total;

передается на сервер номер страници:
params: {
 'filter': this.filter,
 'page': this.pagerPage,
 'onPage': this.pagerOnPage
}

Comment: @PashaThumbaliuk, пагинация рисуется после получения ответа сервера, а не наоборот... Вы можете заранее знать кол-во страниц, но переключать их не надо... Вы лишь отображаете данные полученные сервера..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно такая схема реализации:

- объединить поля `pagerPage` и `pagerOnPage` в объект `query`;
- оставить получение данных только при изменении `query`;
- в наблюдателе `filter` выполнять только сброс страницы `query.pagerPage`.

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      query: {
        pagerPage: 1,
        pagerOnPage: 20,
        // Другие параметры.
        // order_column: 'id',
        // order_direction: 'desc'
      },

      filter: {
        date: '',
        dateTo: '',
        chapter: 'all'
      },

      // Счетчик запросов.
      counter: 0
    }
  },

  watch: {
    query: {
      handler() {
        this.loadList()
      },
      deep: true,
      immediate: true
    },

    filter: {
      handler() {
        this.applyFilter()
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },

  methods: {
    // Сбрасываем фильтр.
    resetFilter() {
      // Наблюдатель за `filter` вызовет `applyFilter` метод.
      this.filter = Object.assign({}, this.filter, {
        date: '',
        dateTo: '',
        chapter: 'all'
      })
    },

    // Применяем фильтр.
    applyFilter() {
      // Наблюдатель за `query` вызовет метод с `ajax` запросом.
      this.query = Object.assign({}, this.query, {
        pagerPage: 1
      })
    },

    loadList() {
      this.counter++
      console.log({
        counter: this.counter,
        filter: this.filter,
        page: this.query.pagerPage,
        onPage: this.query.pagerOnPage
      })
    },

    // Для демо в снипете.
    changePage(page = 1) {
      this.query.pagerPage = parseInt(page, 10)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="filter.chapter">
    <option value="all">Все</option>
    <option value="today">Сегодня</option>
    <option value="tomorrow">Завтра</option>
  </select>
  <input v-model="filter.date" type="date" />
  <input v-model="filter.dateTo" type="date" />

  <hr>Текущая страница: {{ query.pagerPage }}<hr>

  <button type="button" @click="changePage(1)">1</button>
  <button type="button" @click="changePage(2)">2</button>
  <button type="button" @click="changePage(3)">3</button>

  <!-- В вашем проекте
        <v-pagination
            v-model="query.pagerPage" ... />
    -->
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

---

Применение обертки `debounce` оправдано, если у вас есть поисковая строка, например: `query.search`.

```
data() {
  return {
    query: {
      search: '',
      pagerPage: 1,
      pagerOnPage: 20,
    },
    queryWatcher: null,
    // ... остальной код
  }
},

watch: {
  // Оставляем только наблюдатель `filter`.
  // Наблюдатель `query` переносим на
  // хук `mounted`. Визуально просто видно, что
  // при монтировании устанавливается наблюдатель.
}

mounted() {
  this.queryWatcher = this.$watch('query', _.debounce(() => this.loadList(), 1000), {
    immediate: true,
    deep: true
  })
}
```

---

В-остальном же, когда с течением времени количество фильтров разрастается и вы возможно, примите решение добавлять их динамически, то необходимость в автоматическом запросе (без нажатия кнопки), просто отпадает.

В таком случае удаляете наблюдателя за `filter` и добавляете кнопку:

```
<button type="button" @click="applyFilter">Применить фильтр</button>
```

Comment: Хорошое решение. Большое спасибо!

Comment: А как вам решение: повесить функцию loadList на debounce ( https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce ) например на 200мс? Интересно было бы узнать ваше мнение.